# Does actionscript/compiled SWF from Macromedia Flash MX still work with the new Flash plugin?

Tags: flash, actionscript, macromedia, actionscript-1

Starting a project creating a flash game and can't afford to spend money on a license for the newer Flash CSx. I have an old license of Macromedia Studio MX that comes with Macromedia Flash MX v6.0 which has Actionscript 1.0. My question is, are all of the syntax for Actionscript 1.0 and the finalized output SWF still compatible with the new/future flash player plugin?

Comment: As a side note: the output files are SWFs. FLV stands for _FLash Video_ and this is a video file.

Comment: So if I'm exporting the product as a web app, will it stay as a SWF and not compiled into a FLV? Apologies for the ignorance as I'm just learning about Flash technology.

Comment: Yes, the exported file will be SWF (unless you want to export the whole animation as a video, but I believe it's not the case).

Comment: I haven't done much work with flash lately, but working in 1.0 is nuts. Get FlashDevelop, get the SDK, program in 3.0 and output current version files. You can still use your version of flash to create assets, but that's all you need it for. You do not need flash to compile SWFs.

Comment: @Bosworth99 Then testing is just another step or two to compile outside of Flash MX... but besides that I'll be able to fully develop in AS3 if I wanted to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It definitely will work!

You should check if it works correctly in all its parts, because some behaviors has been slightly modified (but this apply much to old SWF file, not to one made present time).

Comment: As a side note: Flash MX also supports AS 2.0

Answer (score 2):

I realize this isn't an answer to your question - but I recommend this:

- install [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/)
- install the [Flex SDK](http://sourceforge.net/adobe/wiki/Projects/) (which adobe provides for free)
- create assets in whatever version of flash / photoshop / gimp you may have access to
- program (in AS3.0)
- compile SWFs in FlashDevelop

Like I noted, I don't do much work in Flash anymore but this is a great workflow. 
Also - Flashdevelop is an amazing IDE. Check out the installation routine for setup.

The other thing about not working in some dusty version of flash is that you won't be tempted to develop timeline based stuff. Flash remains a great technology, at least when it comes to games, and you'll definitely have fun with it.

Check out the numerous libraries (like the epic [Tweenlite](http://www.greensock.com/) or the Pushbutton engine) and you'll be well on your way.

Go forth and prosper.

Comment: +1 truth be told this is the kind of answer that I was looking for... however to obtain this kind of answer, I would've had to ask the question requesting for 'advice' as opposed to a direct answer. So I thank you sir!

Comment: Ah - good on ya. I wish i had time to work in flash These days. Its loads of fun.